# Port forwarding with 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, port-forwarding

i have 1 pc running ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

this pc has 2 network cards:
**enp37s0** (onboard gigabit nic) and **enp38s0** (additional pcie gbit nic).

enp37s0 is connected DIRECTLY to the internet by cable and has PUBLIC STATIC IP.

enp38s0 is used for internal lan and it  is configured  from nmapplet to share the internet from enp37s0 to the rest  of my pcs in the network (13 machines and 1 VM - 10 machines have static ipv4 address, the remaining are using addresses assigned by dhcp).

I would like to do port forwarding , so that i can reach from outside the lan, using my public static address, some services running on my other machines in the lan,  but i am not very expert with iptables neither on cli nor by webmin gui.

can some one point me out some suggestions?

lets suppose i want to forward port 38889 of host 10.42.0.133 so that when i reach my.static.ip.address:38889 ,from outside my lan ,host 10.42.0.133 answers... what should  i do ?

Comment: Please format this properly so it is easy to read. That is a mess and I am having trouble editing it. You should do it yourself. Read these: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: port forwarding is easy enough, but I not not know "nmapplet" (maybe you mean network manager, which as a server person, I don't know either) and wonder if there will be conflict. Use all due caution with a WAN direct connected box and iptables.